# How to manually select the playback resolution for mpd files on mpv

Tags: mpv-media-player

Sometimes I use `mpv` to play ***.mpd*** files. These are either local or streamed files. When the playback starts, `mpv` detects the highest video resolution and audio quality and starts using them.

For example, this is what appears in the terminal window when connecting to a streamed ***.mpd*** file:

```
     Video --vid=1 'bitrate 499950' (h264 640x360 600.000fps)
     Video --vid=2 'bitrate 999965' (h264 768x432 600.000fps)
     Video --vid=3 'bitrate 1999931' (h264 1280x720 600.000fps)
     Video --vid=4 'bitrate 2999896' (h264 1920x1080 600.000fps)
 (+) Video --vid=5 'bitrate 3999862' (h264 1920x1080 600.000fps)
     Audio --aid=1 'bitrate 96000' (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
     Audio --aid=2 'bitrate 128000' (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
     Audio --aid=3 'bitrate 192000' (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
     Audio --aid=4 'bitrate 256000' (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
 (+) Audio --aid=5 'bitrate 320000' (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
Using hardware decoding (vaapi).
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 vaapi[nv12]
AV: 00:00:13 / 01:36:50 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Dropped: 1 Cache: 61s/33MB
```

The **plus** sign shows the automatically selected video and audio.

Is there any way or command to tell `mpv` to use specific video resolutions and audio qualities instead of the automatically detected ones?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it looks like the best options is to select the video and audio stream that you desire from the command line.

**Video stream:**

The relevant *video* options can be seen [here...](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-vid) The *default* of the options is 'auto', where as you have noted mpv selects a stream automagically:

```
--vid=<ID|auto|no>
```

But in your case you will need to select the stream of your choice from `ID`: for example `mpv --vid=3`.

**Audio stream:**

The relevant *audio* options can be seen [here...](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-aid) The *default* of the options is 'auto' where again as you have noted mpv selects a stream automagically:

```
--aid=<ID|auto|no>
```

But in your case you will need to select the stream of your choice from `ID`: for example `mpv --aid=4`.

**References**

- [mpv manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/): The manual for the current stable release of mpv.